# How to add Restrictions to OneToMany mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I was stuck with getting result with @OneToMany mapping. Here are the model classes.

Assessment.java

```
    @Entity
    @FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "tenantIdParam", type = "string"))
    @Filters(@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id = :tenantIdParam"))
    @Table(name = "assessment")
    public class Assessment extends Revenue implements Comparable<Assessment> {

    //other attriutes

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
        private Property propertyAssessment;
    @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false)
        private String tenantId;

//getters and setters
    }
```

Property.java

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "tenantIdParam", type = "string"))
@Filters(@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id = :tenantIdParam"))
@Table(name = "property")
public class Property implements java.io.Serializable {

//other attributes

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mas_gnd_id")
    private GramaNiladhariDivision gramaNiladhariDivision;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mas_so_id", nullable = true)
    private SubOffice subOffice;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mas_ward_id", nullable = true)
    private Ward ward;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mas_road_id", nullable = true)
    private Road road;
    @Column(name = "side_of_property")
    private Character sideOfProperty;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mas_pt_id", nullable = true)
    private PropertyType propertyType;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_description")
    private PropertyDescription propertyDescription;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "propertyAssessment")
    @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Assessment> assessments = new ArrayList<Assessment>(0);
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "property")
    @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<PropertyOwner> propertyOwners = new ArrayList<PropertyOwner>(0);

//getters and setters
}
```

PropertyOwner.java

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "tenantIdParam", type = "string"))
@Filters(@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id = :tenantIdParam"))
@Table(name = "property_owner")
public class PropertyOwner implements java.io.Serializable {

//other attributes

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
    @Column(name = "is_main")
    private Boolean main;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
    private Property property = new Property();
    @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String tenantId;
    @Column(name = "status", columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default 'active'")
    private String status;

//getters and setters

}
```

So my question is I want to load PropertyOwners where status is INACTIVE. I tried to write Criteria in different ways but I couldn't get the exact result. It is always return me all the PropertyOwners regardless of their status even though I add Restriction to the status. Here is one of the Criteria which I tried.

```
public Assessment getAssessmentById(Long assessmentId, Object tenantId) throws HibernateException {
        Session session = getSession(tenantId);
        Assessment result;
        result = (Assessment) session
                .createCriteria(Assessment.class)
                .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .createAlias("propertyAssessment.propertyOwners", "propertyOwners", JoinType.INNER_JOIN,
                        Restrictions.ne("propertyOwners.status", ScandiumKeyBox.INACTIVE))
                .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.subOffice", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.ward", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.gramaNiladhariDivision", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.propertyDescription", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.propertyType", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.road", FetchMode.JOIN).setFetchMode("registerNumber", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .setFetchMode("registerPageNumbers", FetchMode.JOIN).setFetchMode("elgActivity", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("id", assessmentId)).uniqueResult();
        return result;
    }
```

Please provide me a proper solution for this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way to get exact result from the PropertyOwners's status. The tricky part is when retrieve the result hibernate load all the matching entity regardless of the `Restrictions` in `createAlias` because of `JoinType.INNER_JOIN`. So I put `JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN` to the `createAlias` and remove `Restrictions` in `createAlias`. I set the `Restrictions` as usual way. Now it's giving the exact result matching the status.

Here is the modified method.

```
public Assessment getAssessmentById(Long assessmentId, Object tenantId) throws HibernateException {
        Session session = getSession(tenantId);
        Assessment result;
        result = (Assessment) session
            .createCriteria(Assessment.class)
            .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .createAlias("propertyAssessment.propertyOwners", "propertyOwners", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.subOffice", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.ward", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.gramaNiladhariDivision", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.propertyDescription", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.propertyType", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("propertyAssessment.road", FetchMode.JOIN).setFetchMode("registerNumber", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("registerPageNumbers", FetchMode.JOIN).setFetchMode("elgActivity", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", assessmentId))
            .add(Restrictions.ne("propertyOwners.status", ScandiumKeyBox.INACTIVE))
            .uniqueResult();
        return result;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I had the same issue and your solution fixed it. It is not clear to me why hibernate works this way, and why INNERJOIN (which I assume is the default value) does not work.  But thanks to your post I have it working.